# Check if strng value exist in struct array

Tags: arrays, c, loops, struct

I have a struct where the user would enter a number of coordinates of their choosing and label each one. So if they select to enter 3 coordinate they need to label all 3 and give the coordinates. I can loop through all the data and verify if the label exist but I can not assign the struct label with the value if none are found.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

/*Stuct link list */
struct node
{
    double xCoord; 
    double yCoord;
    char label[30];
};

int checkLabel(char* receivedlabel, int coordSize, struct node coord[coordSize])
{
   
    int i,j;
     
     
    if (coordSize == 0)
    {
        
    }
    else
    {
    
    for(i = 0; i<coordSize; i++)
    {
        
         if(strcmp(coord[i].label, receivedlabel)==0)
         {
            j = 0;
            break;
         }
         else 
         {
            j = 1;
         }
}   
}
    
    return j;
}
int main() {
    int i, numOfCoords, j, k;
    double distance;
    double closest = 0;
    double farthest = 0;
    char label[30];
     do //Get the amount of coordinates to enter greater than 2
    {
        printf("How many coords do you want to enter?\nPlease enter more than 2:");
        scanf("%d", &numOfCoords);
        
    }while(numOfCoords <=2);
    
    struct node coords[numOfCoords];
    
    for(i = 0; i < numOfCoords; i++ )
    {
        do
        {
        printf("Please Enter a X Coordinate:");
        scanf("%lf", &coords[i].xCoord);
        printf("Please Enter a y coordinate:");
        scanf("%lf", &coords[i].yCoord);
        }while(coords[i].xCoord<0 || coords[i].yCoord<0);
        if(i==0)
        {
            printf("Please Enter a Label:");
        scanf("%s", &coords[i].label);  
        }
        else
        {
        do
        {
        printf("Please Enter a Label:");
        scanf("%s", &label);
        
        k = checkLabel(label,i, coords);
        if(k == 1)
        {
            *coords[i].label = label;
            }   
        }while(k==0);
        
            
        }
        
    }
    printf("\n");
      for(i = 0; i < numOfCoords-1; i++ )
    {
        for(j = 1; j < numOfCoords; j++)
        {
            
            distance = sqrt(pow(coords[i].xCoord - coords[j].xCoord,2) + pow(coords[i].yCoord - coords[j].yCoord,2)); //Calculate Distance
            if(distance == 0) //If distance equal 0 output no info
            {
                
            }
            else
            {
              //Print out the distance of all coordinates entered   
              printf("The distance between %s:[%lf,%lf] and %s:[%lf,%lf] is %lf\n", coords[i].label, coords[i].xCoord, coords[i].yCoord,coords[j].label, coords[j].xCoord, coords[j].yCoord, distance);     
             if(j==1 && i==0)
          {
            //Set the closet and furthest distance to the first calculated distance
            closest = distance; 
            farthest = distance;
            
          } 
          else
          {
            if(distance > farthest)//If distance is larger than current furthest set furthest equal to current distance
            {
              farthest = distance;
                
            }
            if(distance < closest) //If distance is less than closet set closet equal to current distance
            {
                closest = distance;
            }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
printf("The closet coordinate is %lf and the furthest is %lf\n", closest, farthest);//Display closest and farthest distance
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would help to know if you're receiving a compile error, what it is, and what line it refers to. `*coords[i].label = label;` looks quite wrong. Use `strcpy` to copy strings.

Comment: You can't begin to use any input function correctly unless you ***check the return***. One slip of the key resulting in an invalid `double` value and you go spinning off into an infinite loop.

Comment: You have 4 Warnings that translate into pointer errors in your code. Always compile with warnings enabled and do not accept code until it compiles without warnings. Your problems are on lines 71, 78, 83 and a possible uninitialized `j` returned on line 42. (let your compiler help you with your code)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem can be the way you declaring node, dynamically using numofcoords directly from the reading scanf.

Anyway, Ive wrote a sample, using your code as a starting point and I think i could do what you want.

Please let me know if I can help with anything else!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

/*Stuct link list */
struct node
{
double xCoord; 
double yCoord;
char label[30];
};

int checkLabel(char* receivedlabel, int coordSize, struct node coord[coordSize])
{
    int i,j;
    
    if (coordSize > 0)
    {
        for(i = 0; i<coordSize; i++)
        {
             if(strcmp(coord[i].label, receivedlabel)==0)
             {
                return 0;
             }
        }   
    }
    
    return 1;
}
int main() {
    int i = 0, numOfCoords = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    double distance;
    double closest = 0;
    double farthest = 0;
    char label[30];
    struct node coords[5];
    
    while(numOfCoords <=2) //Get the amount of coordinates to enter greater than 2
    {
        printf("How many coords do you want to enter?\nPlease enter more than 2:");
        scanf("%d", &numOfCoords);
    }
    
    
    for(i = 0; i < numOfCoords; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            printf("Please Enter a X Coordinate:");
            scanf("%lf", &coords[i].xCoord);
            printf("Please Enter a y coordinate:");
            scanf("%lf", &coords[i].yCoord);
        }while(coords[i].xCoord<0 || coords[i].yCoord<0);
        
       
        do{
            printf("Please Enter a Label:");
            scanf("%s", label);strtok(label, "\n");  
            if ( i > 0 && checkLabel(label, i, coords) == 0 ){
                printf("\n");
                continue;
            }
            
            strcpy(coords[i].label,label);
            break;
        }
        while(1);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < numOfCoords; i++ )
    {
        printf("i=%d", i);
        for(j = 0; j < numOfCoords; j++)
        {
            
            distance = sqrt(pow(coords[i].xCoord - coords[j].xCoord,2) + pow(coords[i].yCoord - coords[j].yCoord,2)); //Calculate Distance
            if(distance == 0) //If distance equal 0 output no info
            {
                
            }
            else
            {
                //Print out the distance of all coordinates entered   
                printf("The distance between %s:[%lf,%lf] and %s:[%lf,%lf] is %lf\n", coords[i].label, coords[i].xCoord, coords[i].yCoord,coords[j].label, coords[j].xCoord, coords[j].yCoord, distance);     
                if(j==1 && i==0)
                {
                    //Set the closet and furthest distance to the first calculated distance
                    closest = distance; 
                    farthest = distance;
                } 
                else
                {
                    if(distance > farthest)//If distance is larger than current furthest set furthest equal to current distance
                    {
                        farthest = distance;
                    }
                    if(distance < closest) //If distance is less than closet set closet equal to current distance
                    {
                        closest = distance;
                    }
                }
            }
        
        }
    
    }
    printf("The closet coordinate is %lf and the furthest is %lf\n", closest, farthest);//Display closest and farthest distance
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure it out. Instead of having the user enter the string as a char I opted for using &coords[i].label then I passed that value to the function and it was able to loop through the existing values and if none found assign the value to coords[i].label

Here is my new code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

/*Stuct link list */
struct node
{
    double xCoord; 
    double yCoord;
    char label[30];
};

int checkLabel(char* receivedlabel, int coordSize, struct node coord[coordSize])
{
   
    int i,j;
     
     
    if (coordSize == 0)
    {
        
    }
    else
    {
    
    for(i = 0; i<coordSize; i++)
    {
        
         if(strcmp(coord[i].label, receivedlabel)==0)
         {
            j = 0;
            break;
         }
         else 
         {
            j = 1;
         }
}   
}
    
    return j;
}
int main() {
    int i, numOfCoords, j, k;
    double distance;
    double closest = 0;
    double farthest = 0;
    char label[30];
     do //Get the amount of coordinates to enter greater than 2
    {
        printf("How many coords do you want to enter?\nPlease enter more than 2:");
        scanf("%d", &numOfCoords);
        
    }while(numOfCoords <=2);
    
    struct node coords[numOfCoords];
    
    for(i = 0; i < numOfCoords; i++ )
    {
        do
        {
        printf("Please Enter a X Coordinate:");
        scanf("%lf", &coords[i].xCoord);
        printf("Please Enter a y coordinate:");
        scanf("%lf", &coords[i].yCoord);
        }while(coords[i].xCoord<0 || coords[i].yCoord<0);
        if(i==0)
        {
            printf("Please Enter a Label:");
        scanf("%s", &coords[i].label);  
        }
        else
        {
        do
        {
        printf("Please Enter a Label:");
        scanf("%s", &coords[i].label);
        
        k = checkLabel(coords[i].label,i, coords);
            
        }while(k==0);
        
            
        }
        
    }
    printf("\n");
      for(i = 0; i < numOfCoords-1; i++ )
    {
        for(j = 1; j < numOfCoords; j++)
        {
            
            distance = sqrt(pow(coords[i].xCoord - coords[j].xCoord,2) + pow(coords[i].yCoord - coords[j].yCoord,2)); //Calculate Distance
            if(distance == 0) //If distance equal 0 output no info
            {
                
            }
            else
            {
              //Print out the distance of all coordinates entered   
              printf("The distance between %s:[%lf,%lf] and %s:[%lf,%lf] is %lf\n", coords[i].label, coords[i].xCoord, coords[i].yCoord,coords[j].label, coords[j].xCoord, coords[j].yCoord, distance);     
             if(j==1 && i==0)
          {
            //Set the closet and furthest distance to the first calculated distance
            closest = distance; 
            farthest = distance;
            
          } 
          else
          {
            if(distance > farthest)//If distance is larger than current furthest set furthest equal to current distance
            {
              farthest = distance;
                
            }
            if(distance < closest) //If distance is less than closet set closet equal to current distance
            {
                closest = distance;
            }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
printf("The closet coordinate is %lf and the furthest is %lf\n", closest, farthest);//Display closest and farthest distance
    return 0;
}
```